# Jquery Dashboard with Grid Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm looking to build a Jquery based dashboard. Looking at the following examples:

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

and

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

I see that this functionality is easily accomplished if we have a fluid layout. However. I want a dashboard which is slightly more complex than the examples mentioned above.

The dashboard I'm looking to create will have
a grid where items can be dropped onto. The items can be dropped anywhere on the page, and spacing will be allowed to exist between items.
The items can be resizable against the grid causing items to move out of the way.

I do *not* want a layout like the google homepage dashboard where tiles shift up and do not allow spacing between them in the grid.

So for example I would have a 10 x 10 grid (50 pixels per unit)

A tile can be 1 x 1 and resized to 1 x 2 and then there can be a 1 x 1 spacer and then another tile.

I'm looking for a good algorithm to accomplish this. My ultimate goal is to end up with a dashboard similar to the ones you would see on your android home screens.

However, my major drawback is currently smart collision detection for swapping and organising the grid.

Once accomplished I hope to share my dashboard on github. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a jQuery plugin you can use to do this. Or write one yourself from scratch. *Or* let someone here write one for your which you then post on GitHub? :)

Comment: I'm looking for a Jquery plugin which can assist with this if possible (if it meets my requirements). I'll probably ultimately end up writing my own but I'm looking for a good algorithm or reference implementation to approach this.

Comment: The two links that you provided are a very good start point, you can read the code understand it and then customize it depending on your needs.

Comment: It sounds like there are a couple of UX issues to answer first. How would tiles be resized? By dragging edges? Say on your 10 x 10 grid, I've got 100 tiles (each 1x1). What happens if I resize the top left hand tile to 2x1? Should the tile to the right of it be deleted/removed/push others across? I'd try to think through EVERY UX possibility first and ensure that what you're picturing would be usable. Sorry for the non-answer... from an implementation point of view, you're probably then looking at munging jQuery UI's Sortable and Resizable with some custom logic to handle the UX of resizing.

Comment: Looks like the [Droptiles](https://github.com/oazabir/Droptiles) project could give you a nice starting point. The tiles are not resizable but they may have different sizes.

Comment: @stuCox agreed. The whole ul layout thing becomes an issue. I was going to drag and move things across up to the nearest open space. First Left, then up, then across then down depending on available space. The main issue is just getting the static grid structure out - unlike masonry or isotope which pushes everything up into a fluid layout. The whole sortable portlet approach was an issue due to the nature of how the ul's were treated. So I think that was the bulk of my concern. So to answer your question I'd handle a push approach pushing inside the grid. If a push cannot be handled fail.

Comment: I don't see what the actual question is that's being asked here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a jQuery plugin, but [Gridster](http://gridster.net/) does everything you mentioned EXCEPT for the resizing.

Please let us know if you find something more complete.

Comment: Gridster is a good start. But in fact it doesn't accomplish it in the manner I expect. Definitely upvoting. The grid layout does not allow items to be vertical empty column rows between two widgets as well as not allowing the resizing.

Comment: Little info-update: Gridster is a jQuery plugin with tile resizing support etc. (at least now and as I can see in the demos i tried so far). Even if the info was a bit outdated it helped me pointing to this nice little plugin. Thanks @rowanu ;)